# Visual basic retrieving data from SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I want to retrieve something from a database in vb.net and display it. It has 4 columns with unlimited amounts of rows, could be 5, could be 10.

First column is an `int`, second a `name`, 3rd `date` and 4th a `date`. I have to sort it by date. What would be the best way to retrieve all the data and store it?

One solution I thought of was to store each individual column into an array then sort them, but I am not sure how to sort more than 2 arrays. The next solution I though of was to use a datatable and organizing the columns but I am just not sure how to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: And is there some reason you don't want to sort in SQL as you retrieve the data? Also, how are you ending up displaying the data? Most grid controls can do their own sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to include for SQL:
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection
conn.ConnectionString = "YOUR CONNECTION INFORMATION"

Dim sQuery As String = "SELECT [Number], [Name], [Date], [Date2] " & _
                       "FROM [YourTableName] " & _
                       "ORDER BY [Date]"

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sQuery, conn)
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable()

da.Fill(ds, sQuery)
dt = ds.Tables(0)

dgvYourDataGridView.DataSource = ds
dgvYourDataGridView.Refresh()

conn.Close()
conn.Dispose()
```

Not sure if that's what you're looking for or not.

Comment: This assumes SQL/Server which may or may not be right as the OP doesn't specify what the DB is.

Comment: True, I guess I'm taking on some assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

store the data in a Table inside of a dataset. If you do this then you can select all of the SQL information at once, throw it into the dataset's table and then display it in something like a datagrid.